# Using AysncUDPMessage for ESP32 to send string data

Tags: ethernet, networking, esp32

I am in search for some examples as to how can one use the `AsyncUDPMessage` in an Application for sending out UDP packets to a host with specific IP address and Port number from an **ESP-WROOM-32** (Olimex ESP32-PoE) module?

The Class for [AsyncUDPMessage in arduino-esp32 library](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/AsyncUDP/src/AsyncUDP.h#L25) inherits from `Print`.

I want to send sensor measurements to InfluxDB in the Line Protocol (InfluxDB specific).

#### Example

```
 imu,location=front,nodeid=node1 status=0.00,liac_x=-1.18,liac_y=0.02,liac_z=9.63,eul_x=0.00,eul_y=-6.81,eul_z=0.25 1538507409930
```

The above mentioned example is stored in the form of a `String` and the methods to send information via UDP viz. `send()` `sendTo()` all mention usage of `AsyncUDPMessage` as the first parameter.

#### goal

Send the above measurement to the particular Device's IP and port

```
udp.sendTo(Message, IPAddress(192,168,3,11), 8089);
```

I am currently using `broadcastTo(const char * data, port)` menthod to send information the InfluxDB instance.

#### Code

```
void loop(void) {

  DateTime now_time = rtc.now();

 // create a measurement
  influxMeasurement row("imu");
  row.addTag("location", "front");
  row.addTag("nodeid", "node1");

// get information from BNO055
  imu::Vector<3> li_ac = bno.getVector(Adafruit_BNO055::VECTOR_ACCELEROMETER);
  imu::Vector<3> euler = bno.getVector(Adafruit_BNO055::VECTOR_EULER);
//  Serial.print(li_ac.x());
//  Serial.print(li_ac.y());
  row.addField("status", 0);
  row.addField("liac_x", li_ac.x());
  row.addField("liac_y", li_ac.y());
  row.addField("liac_z", li_ac.z());
  row.addField("eul_x", euler.x());
  row.addField("eul_y", euler.y());
  row.addField("eul_z", euler.z());

  // add timestamp
  row.addTimeStamp_ms(String(now_time.unixtime()) + String(millis()%1000));

  // print the Line Protocol output
  Serial.println(row.postString());

  // UDP Sending 
  char buf[2048]; // make buffer for `broadcastTo()`
  row.postString().toCharArray(buf, sizeof(buf)); // string to char array
  // Serial.println(buf);
  udp.broadcastTo(buf ,8089);
  
  delay(100);
}
```

#### method

I create a Line protocol `String`, make a buffer, convert the string to `char []` and send it out.

#### Question

1. how do I use `AsyncUDPMessage` so I can pass the string to it directly?
2. I am not sure but will `char buf[2048]` within a `loop` is a good idea as every time a buffer allocation might make the ESP32 run out of memory? And if `AsyncUDPMessage` can avoid this concern?

Comment: String has .c_str()

Comment: the library has AsyncUDPClient example

Comment: Yes but there is not mention of `AsyncUDPMessage`. there is only `AsyncUDPPacket`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `udp.print(row.postString().c_str())`

AsyncUDPMessage in AsyncUDP library is only a buffer. It is used only in AsyncUDP send function:

```
size_t AsyncUDPPacket::send(AsyncUDPMessage &message)
{
    return write(message.data(), message.length());
}
```

Comment: So just connect once and then print the information will send the udp to the destination porT?

Comment: udp doesn't connect. only the library takes the server and port parameters in a connect like function. the function can only resolve hostname to IP. but the implementation is hidden in not open source espressif SDK

Comment: if you don't need nonblocking UDP sending, then you don't need the AsyncUDP library